# How to use center-block and vertical align together using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 center-block">
     <div class="icon-circle">
          <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.icon-circle {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The `fa-desktop` is aligned vertically and horizontally centered in the `icon-circle` class. Now I want to align the whole `icon-circle` within the `col-md-3`. But since there is display table cell, the display block in the `center-block` doesn't work. Do you have any idea how could I get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the icon-circle parent need to be in table display mode

```
.col-md-3 {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Use media queries @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }